# Sorting arrays next to other arrays which are the same

Tags: c++, sorting

I just wrote a program where program sorts people by time(minutes).But what and where should I add a code, if minutes are the same and I need to sort seconds as well

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct people{
    string name;
    int min;
    int sec;
};

bool comp(const people &p1, const people &p2) {return (p1.min < p2.min); }

int main() {
    int temp;
    people z[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cin >> z[i].name;
        cin >> z[i].min;
        cin >> z[i].sec;
    }
    sort(z, z + 6, comp);
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << z[i].name << " " << z[i].min << " " << z[i].sec << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
input for example:
John 19 15  
Liza 9 59 
Michael 19 45 
Kira 2 37 
Thomas 5 41 
Justas 19 24
*/
```

Comment: My guess would be where you are comparing the minutes: if the minutes are the same, compare the seconds. So, where exactly is your code doing this? Point your finger to that line, and that's where, obviously, you need to make that change.

Answer (score 2):

A easy way to have a correct comparison function is to use `operator <` of `std::tuple`:

```
bool comp(const people &lhs, const people &rhs)
{
   return std::tie(lhs.min, lhs.sec) < std::tie(rhs.min, rhs.sec);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a conditional for .sec when `p1.min==p2.min`

```
bool comp(const people &p1, const people &p2) {
    return (p1.min < p2.min || p1.min == p2.min && p1.sec < p2.sec); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers of @Jarod42 and @doug will work for sure, but I think this solution is more readable.

```
int getSeconds(const people &p){
    const min2sec = 60.0;
    return p.min * min2sec + p.sec;
}

bool comp(const people &p1, const people &p2) {        
    return (getSeconds(p1) < getSeconds(p2)); 
}
```

The solution of @doug might yield a performance advantage, since you compare the minutes first and only if they are not equal you look at the seconds. 
If performance turns out to be an issue (and measurements proof that this is your hotspot), you can optimise this. Keep in mind that the data structure contains superfluous data (`string name;`) for this operation, which might spoil your performance due to cache line jams.

Comment: This answer also works when the state invariant does not require `sec<60`. While usually the case that `sec<60`, it isn't always. My answer requires this invariant.

Comment: Good point. It is perhaps also a good idea to switch the type from `int` to `unsigned int` for minutes and seconds.

Comment: Yep, that's why date/time is usually in an `uint32_t` relative to some Epoch. Avoids an invariant fail, and is faster for most operations.